# storing rows order in mysql

Tags: mysql, database-design

I need to give the ability to change order of displaying rows to my script admin page.
for that there is a default order for newly added rows (the go to the end of list) and admin should be able to change the position of an specific row.
I'm going to act the rows like a doubly linked list to be able to re-position rows.

- Is it OK to use linked list method for saving the display position of mysql rows?
- Is there a better method?
- Should I use a separate table to store orders or it is OK to add two `next` & `prev` columns to original table?
- Is it possibe then to use mysql `order` statement with this method?

**Edit**: I also thought of using spaced order codes (e.g. 0, 100, 200, ...) but this has a limit that may be reached

Comment: How many rows do you expect to have? The linked list approach is complicated to build while lean, but it takes a lot more power to update all rows with a new order, for example. If you won't have a lot of rows, a simple column which store the current sort order of each works, and you just update them all (all the affected ones >= the change) in batch each time the order changes.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: there can be more than a million row

Comment: A million is a lot to be always batch updating... But it also seems like an unreasonably large amount to be manually ordering. The issue with the linked list is not so much storing it as querying it and getting the right order back.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: actually the table i a feed item list that updates frequently (once or two a day by at least 50 rows); so after a while it will reach that; the ordering thing is not for everything! there is a default order & admin may change the order of one or two items each day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll be better off just storing the ordering position in a dedicated field, instead of trying to implement a linked list.

The issue with the linked list is that is requires some sort of list traversal to "reconstruct" the order before you can display it to the user. Normally, you'd employ a recursive query to do that, but unfortunately MySQL doesn't support recursive queries, so you'll either need to fiddle with stored procedures, or end-up making a database round-trip for each and every list node.

All in all, just updating the order field of several rows from time to time (when you need to reorder) is probably cheaper than traversing the list every time (when you need to display it), especially if you mostly move rows by small distancees. And if you introduce gaps (as you already mentioned), the number of rows that you'll actually need to update will fall dramatically, at the price of increased complexity.

You may also be able to piggy-back the order field onto the [clustering](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index) mechanism offered by InnoDB.

YMMV, of course, but I'd advise benchmarking the simple order field approach on representative amounts of data before attempting to implement anything more sophisticated...